# living trust/estate disbursing funds from the sale of a house to beneficiaries?

Tags: tax-law

I'm the trustee for my mom's living trust who just passed away and will be disbusing funds from the sale of a house to my siblings, the beneficiaries. This is not taxable as it’s under the inheritance tax thresholds and not from interest or dividends that might go on a K-1.  Are there any forms I need to send with the check or ask them to fill out such as a W9? I’m getting mixed answers on this, I asked a friend who is a retired IRS auditor and he said nothing is needed since it’s non taxable and an attorney said just to be safe have them fill out a W-9? Opinions?

Comment: You need to hire a lawyer or accountant